# SQL Editor In java

Tags: java

I have created Database Editor Java Web Application & i want to search text box in jsp file like below image....

[image]

Comment: *and what have you tried to achieve this?*

Comment: Can you please edit the question? its un understandable

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't a free coding service

Answer (score 1):

You can use `java.sql.DatabaseMetaData` to get a list of the tables in a schema.

```
Connection conn = ...; // the JDBC connection

DatabaseMetaData metaData = conn.getMetaData();
ResultSet resultSet = metaData.getTables("catalog", "schemaPattern", "tableNamePattern", null);
```

See the API documentation of [`getTables(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getTables-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String:A-) for more detailed usage information.